# Http GET Request error in android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get a response from a http get request on android, without using the map activity, only sending a url request to get a response to a string.

The url to get the response from:
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=ashdod&destinations=yavne&key

and the code I am trying is:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
    URL url = null;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url  = new URL(urlString.toString());
        urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        InputStream inStream = null;
        inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        String temp = "";
        while((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null){
            //Parse data
            response += temp;
        }
        bReader.close();
        inStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        JSONObject Jresponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONArray rows = Jresponse.getJSONArray("rows");
        JSONObject rows_obj = (JSONObject) rows.get(0);
        JSONArray elems = rows_obj.getJSONArray("elements");
        JSONObject elems_obj = (JSONObject) elems.get(0);
        JSONObject dist = (JSONObject) elems_obj.get("distance");
        JSONObject dur = (JSONObject) elems_obj.get("duration");
        finalDistance = dist.getInt("value");
        finalDuration = dist.getInt("value");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the problem is that it is throwing an exception when it reaches the connect.

P.S. This is my first time with android so please be kind with me.

Comment: can you add exception stack trace

Comment: and the exception class

Answer (score 3):

When doing GET request, you do not need to do output.

Just remove this line:

`urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);`

or you can simply change `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true)` to `urlConnection.setDoOutput(false)`

Apart from this, you should also change this part of code to prevent garbled code:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```